# Get device shadow in Android without cognito pool id

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, shadow, amazon-cognito, aws-iot

I found that device pool id is required to get shadow details using Android SDK with CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider. Is it possible to obtain shadow details without using the pool id as in node js or java library?

Comment: [*"The Thing Shadows service accepts two forms of authentication: Signature Version 4 with IAM credentials or TLS mutual authentication with a client certificate."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/API_GetThingShadow.html)  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I was working with this particular sample https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/TemperatureControl/src/com/amazonaws/demo/temperaturecontrol/TemperatureActivity.java . Relative to this i wanted to access the shadow without using cognito pool id, using MQTT protocol.

Comment: +1
Below android sdk sample explains IoT authentication using Cognito poolID.
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/AndroidPubSub/README.md

Can someone please share IAM credentials based authentication for AWS IoT using android SDK.